# Possible to use CtrlP to interactively search file contents?

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

Is it possible to have the CtrlP plugin call out to grep? *(git-grep in this case, although I don't expect it makes a big difference)*.

So it searches the file contents instead of simply listing the files?

Something like Emacs [counsel-git-grep](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), see: [example demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEmXQNS7ofo).

---

Notes:

1. I've seen some hints that this is possible, but couldn't manage to get it 
   working.
2. I'm aware of `fzf` but it seems this depends on external tools that aren't portable across Linux/OSX/Win32.